# How do you differentiate "thru", "threw", "through", and "thorough"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adverbs, confusables

How do I know which word to use in the correct context?

How do I recognize these words when hearing them?

Examples:

> Jimmy **threw** the ring at Emiko.
>
> Elvis walked **through** the door.
>
> John was **through** with work for the day.
>
> Gareth was **through** with mosquitoes coming **through** the window!
>
> Edward was very **thorough** when cleaning the kitchen.

Comment: I can't understand your question honestly... "How do which word to use in the correct place?"

Comment: Thanks to @Billare for correction. By the way, I was going to answer but my honest opinion is that it doesn't really sound like an actual question.

Comment: @Billare..Thanks a lot for editing the question..i will keep this in mind next time when i post a question

Comment: @Alenanno Actuly i used to get confused which word fits best in the context....lots of confusions at that time

Comment: For the second question, "threw", "through", and "thru" are all homophones, meaning they are pronounced the same, as /θruː/. "Thorough" is pronounced /θəroʊ/

Comment: You can only do it through context of the situation or sentence when you hear it.

Comment: Also check this https://askanydifference.com/difference-between-threw-and-through/ these are confusing for sure. Threw is like throwing a ball but with past tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**thorough** is not a synonym with either thru, threw and through, it means something completely different.

> **through**  is used in reference to a
>   movement or passage that proceeds
>   linearly through  is quite common,
>   while **thru**  is nonstandard and should
>   be avoided

http://thesaurus.com/browse/through

**Threw** (Past tense of throw)

> propel something through the air

http://thesaurus.com/browse/threw

Comment: OK, although just saying "nonstandard and should be avoided" is simply a value judgement and doesn't explain anything about when the form is actually used. My observation would be that it tends to be used in cases where there is a need to save space and/or for dramatic effect (e.g. advertising, titles, LED displays...). N.B. "thru" is rarely used in the UK.

Comment: @NeilCoffey - I would put it this way: When **is** it used? When an advertiser wants to save space or be cute.  When *should* it be used?  **Never**.

Comment: Through and threw are not synonyms, either.  They are "homonyms" or "homophones", words that sound the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think people are understanding your question. You are asking how can tell the difference between 'threw', 'through', 'thorough' when you are hearing them being said, right?

> Jimmy threw the ring at Emiko.
>
> Elvis walked through the door.
>
> John was through with work for the day.
>
> Gareth was through with mosquitoes coming through the window!
>
> Edward was very thorough when cleaning the kitchen.

### Pronunciation

You can tell 'thorough' apart from the others through it's pronunciation.

It's different. If somebody has a thick accent though I guess 'thorough' might sound like 'throw' if somebody is not careful in their annunciation.

which brings me to

### Context

The context is what will help you.

> Jimmy threw the ring at Emiko.

The meaning is that a person named Jimmy tossed a ring to another person.

> Elvis walked through the door.

(Concrete)
A person named Elvis walked in a part of space that is, or is usually occupied by a solid object. So you can't walk into a room if the door is closed. (Solid Object) but when the door is open you can walk 'through' it. (The example isn't easy to use since in reality you are walking through the door frame but that's not how language works, unless you want to be pedantic.)

> John was through with work for the day.

(Abstract)
John was done with work, he wasn't going to continue work. It's meaning is the same as the sentence with Elvis but the context is different. Instead of a physical object, it's a task or a dedicated time of day, where once he had passed the time, or completed his task, he had moved to the other side of the object, by doing the task. This might be better. Elvis moved through the door frame and ended up on the other side.

> Gareth was through with mosquitoes coming through the window!

The first through is the same as the previous sentence, the second the same as the Elvis sentence.

### the point

Using context you can see the difference. Jimmy couldn't through the ring at Emiko unless he did something to the ring.

*Subject* + **Verb**

*Jimmy* **threw** the ring at Emiko

*Jimmy* **jumped** through the ring and **lunged** at Emiko

Where did he throw the ring = at Emiko
Where did he jump = Through the ring

Answer (score 1):

“thorough” is a completely different word, which isn't pronounced remotely like “thru”, “threw”, and “through”. “thru” is an unorthographic writing of “through”. So, the remaining ambiguity (between “threw” and “through”) must just be decided by context.

Comment: Isn't it clearer to only say " “thorough” isn't pronounced remotely like “thru”, “threw”, and “through”", because "threw" is also completely different word than "through".

Comment: Love your use of "unorthographic".  I might have said "heterographic".

Answer (score -2):

I would say that the word thru is used mostly when you are discusssing something pertaining to the past, or if it is dealing with passing something or someone. You could say " I came thru there last night." It could mean you were between cities or states, but you were traveling.  Passing one place to get to another.  "I went past there, or I am passing thru your part of town tomorrow.  The words thru, through, and threw, the latter two have two entirely different meanings.  Through means to go through something it could be emotionally, showing feelings, for something or someone.  Through is meant to be used when you are sharing an experience with another person. It is personal actually. It is like an accomplishment.  The word threw, as we all know means to throw something at someone, or throw an object aiming to hit a target.

Comment: The "*thru*" spelling is just an incorrect spelling of *through*.